# Step Number from 10 to N using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> The Program must accept an integer N. The program must print all the stepping number from 10 to N, if there is no such number present the program should print -1 as the output .
>
> A number is called stepping number if all adjacent digits have an absolute difference of 1
>
> The `code Works perfectly` I just need to reduce the time limit for the `maximum possible test case`
> I wrote the code in python where i approached this problem using `brute force`, but the code didn't succeed because of the time limit

```
def isStepNum(n):
    lst_num = str(n)
    for i in range(len(lst_num)-1):
        if abs(int(lst_num[i])-int(lst_num[i+1]))!=1:
            return 0
    return 1
a=int(input())
if a<10:
    print(-1)
# brute force approach to iterate all the integers from 10 to a
for i in range(10,a+1):
    if isStepNum(i):
        print(i,end=" ")
```

```
Boundary   : 1<=N<=10^7
Time Limit : 500 ms
```

Example:

```
Input : 12 
Output : 10 12
```

```
Input : 100
Output: 10 12 21 23 32 34 43 45 54 56 65 67 76 78 87 89 98
```

```
Input : 5
Output : -1
```

Is there any way to reduce the amount of time to execute ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain your algorithm in words?

Comment: Are you required to return the data in sorted order?

Comment: What should the output of 120 and 160 look?

Comment: @zedfoxus for 120 , it should be `10 12 21 23 32 34 43 45 54 56 65 67 76 78 87 89 98 101` and  for 160 it should be `10 12 21 23 32 34 43 45 54 56 65 67 76 78 87 89 98 101 121 123`

Comment: @Nick Yes it is required to be sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the generation of numbers by noting that each time a digit is added to an existing stepping number it must be either 1 more or 1 less than the existing last digit. So we can generate all the stepping numbers with a given number of digits by starting with single digit numbers (1-9) and then repeatedly adding digits to them until we have reached the number of digits we want. So for example, starting with the digit `1`, and needing to go to 4 digits, we would produce

```
1 => 10, 12
10, 12 => 101, 121, 123
101, 121, 123 => 1010, 1012, 1210, 1212, 1232, 1234
```

The number of digits we need is computed by using `math.ceil(math.log10(N))`.

```
import math

def stepNums(N):
    if N < 10:
        return -1
    digits = math.ceil(math.log10(N))
    sn = [[]] * digits
    # 1 digit stepping numbers
    sn[0] = list(range(1, 10))
    # m digit stepping numbers
    for m in range(1, digits):
        sn[m] = []
        for s in sn[m-1]:
            if s % 10 != 0:
                sn[m].append(s * 10 + s % 10 - 1)
            if s % 10 != 9:
                sn[m].append(s * 10 + s % 10 + 1)
    return [s for l in sn for s in l if 10 <= s <= N]
```

e.g.

```
print(stepNums(3454))
```

Output:

```
[10, 12, 21, 23, 32, 34, 43, 45, 54, 56, 65, 67, 76, 78, 87, 89, 98, 101, 121, 123, 210, 212, 232, 234, 321, 323, 343, 345, 432, 434, 454, 456, 543, 545, 565, 567, 654, 656, 676, 678, 765, 767, 787, 789, 876, 878, 898, 987, 989, 1010, 1012, 1210, 1212, 1232, 1234, 2101, 2121, 2123, 2321, 2323, 2343, 2345, 3210, 3212, 3232, 3234, 3432, 3434, 3454]
```

Note that the code could potentially be sped up by comparing the generated numbers to `N` so that when calling `stepNums(10001)` we don't generate all the numbers up to `98989`.

Comment: Can you explain this program ,please

Comment: Nice code, @Nick!! Thanks for sharing. The route I was taking was something on the lines of memoizing 12, for example, flipping the numbers around to get 21 and skip ahead. Your solution is very effective.

Comment: @Altair please see my edit, I've added an explanation that I hope is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the main trick here is that the max range is 10^7. If we consider each digit as a node of the graph, we can traverse it with bfs/dfs and at each point, we can only move to the adjacent node (digit + 1, digit -1). Because the maximum depth is only 7, the solution should be pretty fast.

Here's a rough DFS implementation, you can improve the details.

```
sol_list = []
def dfs(i, num, N):
  # print(i, num)
  if num > N: # too much, need to break
    return
  if num <= N and num >= 10: # perfect range, add to solution, I can add some repeated solution as I called dfs(i+1,0,N) multiple times
    global sol_list
    # print(num)
    sol_list.append(num) # add to solution

  if i > 7:
    return
  if num == 0: # I can call another 0
    dfs(i+1, 0, N) # this is not needed if the numbers are added in the previous list without checking
  last_dig = num % 10
  if last_dig == 0:
      dfs(i+1, num*10 + 1, N) # if last digit is 0, we can only choose 1 as next digit not -1
  elif last_dig == 9:
    dfs(i+1, num*10 + 8, N)
  else:
    dfs(i+1, num*10 + (last_dig-1), N)
    dfs(i+1, num*10 + (last_dig+1), N)

import time
t1 = time.time()
[dfs(0, i, 10000000) for i in range(10)] # staring with every digit possible 0-9
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
sol = sorted(set(sol_list))
print(sol) # added some repeated solutions, it's easier to set them
```

Comment: Very nice. You'll just have to sort it at the end and ensure that numbers are not repeated.

Comment: It seems my code is about 2-3x faster than this, possibly because of the overhead of all the function calls. https://rextester.com/CISBC17600

Comment: yes, but still it is under the time limit. For me, I find dfs much more intuitive, I can definitely optimize the dfs but yes your solution is better in terms of speed.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet. I will explain the idea of Nick's algorithm here.

1. Create 1-digit number list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
2. Create 2-digit number list by combining number `k` in 1-digit number list with k*10 + (k-1) or k*10 + (k+1), for example `3` will generate `32` or `34`
3. Repeat the step 2 until reaches m-digit number. `m` is calculated before.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
from itertools import accumulate
import time

def main(n):
    result=set()
    for length in range(2,7):
        dxss=list(product([-1,1],repeat=length-1))
        for initial in range(1,10):
            for dxs in dxss:
                ans=list(accumulate(dxs,initial=initial))
                if all([(y in range(0,10)) for y in ans]):
                     result.add(int("".join(map(str,ans))))
    sorted_lst=sorted(result)
    return [x for x in sorted_lst if x<n]

n=10000000
start=time.time()
lst=main(n)
stop=time.time()
print("time={0}[s]".format(stop-start))
print(lst)
```

time=0.0020003318786621094[s]

[10,12,21,...989898]

Step number definition is "(nth digit - n-1th digit)= 1 or -1".

N is 10 < N < 10**7.Therefore, I must decide 1st number(1or2or..9) and 6 dx constructed by 1 or -1.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged. Please consider explaining your method.